# [qemu]Stay black screen!I think this phenomenon from kernel's config file

Tags: kernel, config, qemu

when I use qemu to simulate 3.10.88 kernel on my debian9.6,there is nothing on my compute(At least it should give me something-_-).There are some information about my works.

**Information**
1.qemu's parameter

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -m 1G \
    -kernel ./bzImage \
    -hda ./amd64.ext2 \
    -nographic \
    -append "root=/dev/sda init=/sbin/init console=ttyS0"
```

2.The config that I used is x86_64_defconfig
3.picture
[image]

**question:**
1.when I used the [kernel](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/amd64/linux-image-3.10.0-1-generic/3.10.0-1.8),same as the configure of the qemu,it is work well.
2.I extracted the config file from [linux-image-3.10.0-1-generic_3.10.0.8_amd64.deb](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/143659377/linux-image-3.10.0-1-generic_3.10.0-1.8_amd64.deb).I am going to compare between config-3.10.0-1-generic and x86_64_defconfig.[compare result](https://github.com/jiangqii/kernel_3.10.88_config/tree/master/Linux)
[image]

and I add some options in x86_64_defconfig from config-3.10.0-1-generic.
3.Is there a general way to solve such problems?（I can't see anything here）

Thanks!

**supplement**
I add information from config-3.10.0-1-generic into x86_64_config,but it's not work.So I use GDB to debug.And I find kernel seems to stop at this place:(Sure ,I type Ctrl+C 2000 years later)
[image]

[arch/x86/kernel/head_64.S](https://github.com/jiangqii/kernel_3.10.88_config/blob/master/Linux/head_64.S)

So,I initially thought it was stuck here.Is it going to be the problem?